# Cauchy sequence $a_n = 1 + \frac12 + \frac14 + ... + \frac{1}{2^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, cauchy-sequences

For the sequence $a_n = 1 + \frac12 + \frac14 +  ... + \frac{1}{2^n}$, $n \ge 1$, find a formula $N = N(\epsilon)$ such that
for all $\epsilon > 0$ and for all $m,n \ge N(\epsilon)$, $|a_m - a_n| < \epsilon$.

I have tried many things but it's just not working. I know that the condition is the definition of Cauchy sequences. But that didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried writing what $a_n-a_m$ is?

Comment: You may notice that $|a_m-a_n|<1/2^N$. Thus you can choose $\epsilon$ accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

\begin{align*}
a_n
&= 1 + \frac12 + \frac14 + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n} \\
&= \frac{1}{2^n} (2^n + 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + \cdots + 1) \\
&= \frac{2^{n+1} - 1}{2^n} = 2 - \frac{1}{2^n}
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
|a_n - a_m| &= \left| \left( 2 - \frac{1}{2^n} \right) - \left( 2 - \frac{1}{2^m} \right) \right| \\
&= \left| \frac{1}{2^n} - \frac{1}{2^m} \right| \\
&< \frac{1}{2^m} + \frac{1}{2^n} \\
&\le \frac{1}{2^N} + \frac{1}{2^N} = \frac{2}{2^N}
\end{align*}

Pick $N(\epsilon)$ so that $\frac{2}{2^N} < \epsilon$.

Comment: But doesn't N(epsilon) has to be in the form of: N= some equation in terms of epsilon?
How would we get there by just knowing that 2/2^n < epsilon and that N>n

Comment: @ZZZZZZzzzzzz  Good question; one way is just to pick $N > \frac{2}{\epsilon}$ (such an $N$ exists by the archimedian property) and then we have $$\frac{2}{2^N} < \frac{2}{N} < \frac{2}{2 / \epsilon} = \epsilon.$$

Comment: @ZZZZZZzzzzzz And just to clarify, $N$ doesn't have to be an "equation" in terms of epsilon necessarily; it just has to be some function of $\epsilon$.  So you can just say, let $N$ be some integer such that $N > \frac{2}{\epsilon}$.

Comment: got it!
i was thinking something along the lines of:
since 2/2^n < epsilon then n > log[base2] (2/epsilon)
and since N(epsilon)>= n. Then N(epsilon)>log[base2](2/epsilon)
wouldn't that work?

Comment: @ZZZZZZzzzzzz That works too; I was being cautious just in case you hadn't yet defined the function $\log_2$ in the class.  In my analysis class we didn't rigorously define $\log_2$ until much after doing Cauchy sequences, and therefore we wouldn't have been allowed to use it.

Comment: I see! to be honest, we didn't define Log yet, but the teacher have used logs in class before and he didn't mention anything about not using them. But yeah you are right, i mean that is the point of an analysis class, is just to build everything based on basic definitions and not take anything for granted. anyways, thank you so much. I appreciate your help!